# Приостановить цикл Python до выполнения определенного условия

Tags: python, циклы

```
exe_loop = True
while exe_loop == True:
    for line_ in code:
        string += 1
        line = line_.split(' ')

        if line[0] == '-':
            wait()
            while cont == False:
                continue
```

Этот код должен читать текстовый файл, разбивать его сначала на строки, а потом на слова, и при встрече слова "-" - тормозиться до тех пор, пока не будет нажата определенная клавиша.

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: Можно просто `input()` там поставить, будет ждать до клавиши ввод.

Comment: Хотя всё-равно непонятно в чём смысл, входные данные то уже не поменяются, поэтому неважно, сразу их обработать или после паузы.

Comment: этот фрагмент используется в Tkinter в отдельном потоке, он необходим, чтобы читать инструкции для программы из файла

Answer (score 0):

> этот фрагмент используется в Tkinter в отдельном потоке, он необходим, чтобы читать инструкции для программы из файла

В модуле Tkinter есть метод [**bind**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) (Button.bind) ,который может обрабатывать нажатия на клавиши.

```
button = Button(text="Кнопка")
def test(event):
    print("Кнопка нажата")
button.bind("<Enter>", test)
```

Ещё пара примеров - **[раз](https://pythonru.com/uroki/obrabotka-sobytij-i-nastrojka-okna-tkinter)** **[два](https://webfanat.com/article_id/?id=117)**